# Sound playback delay (hiccup) when OpenAL is implemented on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delay, openal, hiccup

I implemented OpenAL code to my iphone game. When I starts the game, it runs for 1 sec and stalls for 2 sec then resumes (hiccup effect). I believe its delayed due to the sound files loading. What is the solution? Can anyone recommend any book, site or sources code (not the iphone reference, please)? Is there a loading process and where should I initialize the loading process? Would that help?

Below, I have included the related components of the OpenAL code that I have implemented. The sound file will be played and invoked by a "if" statement in the gameloop. The OpenALController class is for the sound sources and buffers creation and the **InitOpenAL** method is invoked in **OpenALController**.  MyView is a customized subclass of UIView and connected to the main view (I didn't use the default view).

> // MyView.m
>   // A customized UIView as the main view.
>       #import "OpenALSoundController.h"
>       - (void)startPlaying{
>       ...
>       [self initializeValuables];
>       ...
>   [self initializeTimer];
>   }
>   - (void)initializeTimer {
>           if (theTimer == nil) {
>               theTimer = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector)gameLoop)];
>       theTimer.frameInterval = 2;
>       [theTimer addToRunLoop: [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
>   }
>       }
>   - (void)gameLoop {
>   ...
>      If something = true
>      // Play the sound
>      [[OpenALSoundController sharedSoundController] playSound1];
>   ...
>   }
>   ...
>   @end

---

> //  OpenALSoundController.h
>   @interface OpenALSoundController : NSObject {
>   ...}
>   ...
>   + (OpenALSoundController*) sharedSoundController
>   ...
>   @end

---

> //  OpenALSoundController.m
>   // Singleton accessor
>   {
>       static OpenALSoundController* shared_sound_controller;
>       @synchronized(self)
>       {
>           if(nil == shared_sound_controller)
>           {
>               shared_sound_controller = [[OpenALSoundController alloc] init];
>           }
>           return shared_sound_controller;
>       }
>       return shared_sound_controller;
>   }
>   - (void) initOpenAL{
>   ...
>       file_url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fire" ofType:@"wav"]];
>       firePcmData = MyGetOpenALAudioDataAll((CFURLRef)file_url, &data_size, &al_format,&sample_rate);
>       alBufferData(fireOutputBuffer, al_format, firePcmData, data_size, sample_rate);
>       [file_url release];
>   ...
>   alSourcei(outputSourceFire, AL_BUFFER, fireOutputBuffer);
>   ...
>   }

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Finch](https://github.com/zoul/Finch), an OpenAL sound engine for iOS. It’s very well suited to games. It’s usually better to reuse some already existing code than develop and maintain your own.

Answer (score 0):

First its better to use mp3, as wav files are huge and loading from disk takes time. Mp3 files are smaller on disk, loaded into memory and decompressed there for playing. Try experimenting by reducing mp3 bitrate/encoding quality too.

Also you need to preload sounds to avoid hiccups, otherwise you will have a delay the first time a sound is played.